# Access violation in DLL if compiled with vc++ compiler version lower than VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to figure this out for weeks now ... Whenever I compile my D3D proxy dll with plattform toolset VS2013 (vs120) or lower I get an access violation (0xC0000005) in the D3D9 application using this library.
If I change to VS2015 or VS2017 the exception does not occur.

My dll does only contain a reimplementation of the DirectX 9 Interfaces IDirect3D9 and IDirect3DDevice9 (working as a raw proxy dll).

The reason I want to use VS2013 is that my closed source D3D9 application has been compiled using VS2013. If I understood correctly using different VS runtimes often does not work properly which probably is also the reason that all my attempts to log all calls to D3D9 methods to a file led to runtime errors.

I am on Windows 8.1 Pro by the way.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: *If I change to VS2015 or VS2017 the exception does not occur* -- It's time to start debugging (or learn  how to debug) your application and see exactly what function, which line, etc. is causing the exception.  An access violation can be caused by many reasons, one being a bug in your code that is revealed by the different compiler.

Comment: Apparently I was not clear enough. _The reason I want to use VS2013 is that my closed source D3D9 application has been compiled using VS2013._ By that I meant the closed source application of which I am trying to intercept the D3D9 calls. I've got no source code for the part where the exception gets thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your DLL is compiled with ideally `/LD` or `/LDd` (depending whether it is debug or release version) or at least `/MD` or `/MDd`, to use the runtime linked dynamically, i.e. do not build with `/MT` or `/MTd` (AFAIK the default is `/MT[d]` at least in some cases, but I'm not currently sure about the default DLL settings).

Also, depending on what calling convention the application expects, you can try to play with changing the default calling convention: `/Gz` (stdcall), `/Gr` (fastcall), `/Gd` (cdecl). Often stdcall is expected by libraries, but the default in MSVC is AFAIK cdecl, so that might be a source of issues as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that when I am back at work again. 
But let me ask in advance: The only thing I change is the plattform toolset, nothing else. Is it really possible that /MT and /MTd work with v140/v141 but not with v120? If yes, then why? Thanks.

Comment: I checked the settings - /LD and /LDd are not available, but /MD is set.